# How to install gcc 6.4.1 on Fedora 26

Tags: yum, gcc, dnf

I'm trying to build CORE Network Emulator from source and I seem to have hit [this gcc7 bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1473425), so I want to install gcc 6.4.1 but when I try to run `dnf install gcc-6.4.1` I get the error `No package gcc-6.4.1 available`

How can I install gcc-6.4.1?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing gcc 6.4, I have changed the compiler's settings.

The problem is that when you use the switch `-Werror` all warnings are treated as errors, and the warning about using an `int` for a `bool` killed the compilation.

I added switch: `-Wno-int-in-bool-context` which treats that warning as a warning, like it should, so that the compilation continues.

See also:

gcc warning options:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

patch for CORE compiler flags:
https://github.com/coreemu/core/pull/129/files